# Eclipse Out of Memory

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a ATG Dust Application. To test my ATG application, i linked my ATG App to Dust Application by Right clicking on Dust App -> Build Path -> Link Source -> Select my ATG App.  ATG app is a big application. When i try to clean build the DUSt App, i get the exception like "An out of memory exception has occurred. Consult the " Running Eclipse"section....."

In the eclipse .log file has the following exception logged,

```
// From the Log File   
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-03-27 06:56:26.549
    !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching SampleTest".
    !STACK 0

// Exception
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try increasing your heap size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: what is your question? You just tell us what you have and not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

just right-click on your file in eclipse and select as Run as -> Run configuration .
It will open Run Configurations Dialog Box .Click on Arguments Tab

Enter this value

```
                    -Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
```

In Vm Arguments and press run

Comment: if it works, for you, please don't forget to vote this answer so that others will find answers easily related with the heap space out of memory problem.

Comment: I get this error,Error occurred during initialization of VM
The size of the object heap + VM data exceeds the maximum representable size

Comment: You can set heap size at the project level also, and if your project is maven based, you can set in pom.xml also.

Comment: "VM data exceeds the maximum representable size " means that you assigned more memory to your application than you have physical RAM on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Out of Memory issue is something that occurs due to the improper handling of Heap. You must optimise the code to avoid that. As a temporary fix you can increase the heap space.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: +1 for "improper handling of Heap". Increasing xmx alone might only help until the next release of ones code.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dileep said, the problem is possibly an improper handling of heap space.

Increased heapsize might not solve the problem, but work around it for a while. You can set the parameter `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` in your `eclipse.ini`. This will write a heapdump out, which can be analzed by tools like [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Try to make sure that you don't have a memory leak before using up more space.

in your case `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange` is copying parts of Arrays around. you could start with checking what size they are.