# Eclipse "OutOfMemoryError" After Reading Large Code File Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, out-of-memory

I have a Java implemented program that reads a MATLAB code repository, calculates metrics for each of the files and stores the result in a HashMap where the key is the file in question and the value is a list of integers which stores the values for each of the calculated metrics. I ran it on a code repository which contains 3600 files without a problem. However, when i try to run it on a code repository which contains over 30.000 MATLAB files, i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Is there any possible way to get around this?

UPDATE (02/11/2016): eclipse.ini file content addedd

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Current_User\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx8192m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Comment: Another possible answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704852/eclipse-out-of-memory

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work...

Comment: How much total memory do you have and how large is your heap?

Comment: My computer has a total of 12gb of memory. And i enlarged my heap up to 8gb.

Comment: Update your question (use [edit]) and include the entire contents of your `eclipse.ini` file.  Also, you just may be exceeding the capacity of your system.

Comment: Question updated with eclipse.ini file.

Comment: You still have not provided enough information.  If the 30,000 files add up to more than 8GB of data then you're going to need a bigger computer.

Comment: The 30,000 files only take up 237 MB. Anyway, what more information do you need?

Comment: The files may take only 237MB (8KB each?) but the in-memory data structures might be much larger.